# Does a For-loop process a function inside the expression until the loop ends?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

```
var x = myFunction(y);
for (let index = 0; index < x; index++) {
  //do something
}
```

Question: Does **x** inside the loop expression have to run myFunction every time it loops in order to get the value for **x**?

If so, would it be better(or matter) to just write the For-loop as:

```
for (let index = 0; index < myFunction(y); index++) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the function is only called when you explicitly call it, with `myFunction(y)`. After you call it, the return value is stored into the `x` variable. Then, inside the loop, on every iteration, all that happens is that the existing `x` variable is compared against `index`.

Your first code is more efficient.

Referencing a variable *alone* will only ever result in a function call and possible side-effects if the variable is a property of the global object, and it's a getter:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
  get () {
    console.log('function running');
  }
});

foo;
foo;
foo;
```

This is extremely unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no** because JavaScript evaluate first the value of **myFunction(y)** then assign it to x before now moving to the for loop.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Instead, it will be yes if this insctruction **var z = myFunction(y)** was inside the **for-loop**

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  Let's test it and find out.

```js
var counter = 10;

var x = myFunction();

for (let index = 0; index < x; index++) {
  console.log('index: '+index);
}

function myFunction(){
  counter--;
  return counter;
};
```

Nope. It appears that x is evaluated once.